# How to toggle the contents of span when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with a drop down menu. I have a + in front of the drop down menu inside a span. I would like the the plus to toggle to - when the menu is dropped down and back to + when the menu is up(hidden). How can I do this?

my html looks like

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li class="shop"><a href="#"><span>+</span>Shop</a>
            <ul class="shopList">
                <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jumpsuits</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="wholesale.php">Wholesale</a></li>
        <li><a href="retailers.php">Retailers</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I am currently using js to drop down my menu. Can I add to my current js to achieve this. My js looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shop').click(function() {
            $('.shopList').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

here is my css

```
nav{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   width:70%;
   margin:0;
   padding:3px 15%;
   border-top:1px solid #d0d0d0;
   text-align:center;
   font:15px 'OpenSans';
   z-index: 999;
}
nav ul{
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
nav li{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0 10px;
   padding:0;
}
nav li ul li{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   width:150px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.shopList{
   position:absolute;
   display:none;
   width:100px;
   margin:0 0 0 -50px;
   padding:0;
}
nav a{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   width:auto;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   color:#707070;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to compare previous text with new:

```js
    $('.shop').click(function() {
      $('.shopList').slideToggle("fast");
      $("a span", this).text() == "+" ? $("a span", this).text("-") : $("a span", this).text("+");
    });
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 15%;
  border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
  font: 15px'OpenSans';
  z-index: 999;
}
nav ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
nav li ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.shopList {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #707070;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="shop"><a href="#"><span>+</span>Shop</a>
      <ul class="shopList">
        <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dresses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Jumpsuits</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="wholesale.php">Wholesale</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="retailers.php">Retailers</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Im sorry I should have included my css. my shoplist class starts as hidden and show only after click.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have included my css above. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I cant get it to work. My dropdown menu no longer drops down. I have uploaded to the live site so you can get an example www.shopadhira.com

Comment: Uncomment document ready event from your code. In code snippet runs on dom ready so isn't need but in your site is it need it :)

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks for the quick replies and for the help.